# Argument of type '' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindConditions<Entity>' TypeOrm Order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, orm, typeorm

I'm trying to order by the mongodb _id field in descending order. My Query is given below:

```
this.vehicleRepository.findOne({
                        where : 
                           {
                            "vin": vin.vin,
                            "userId": user.Id
                        },
                        order: {
                            id : "DESC"
                        }
                    });
```

But it keeps giving me the error:

```
Argument of type '' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindConditions<Entity>' TypeOrm Order
```

The model file is

```
import { Column, Entity, ObjectID, ObjectIdColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Vehicle {

   @ObjectIdColumn()
    public id: ObjectID;
}
```

The repository is :

```
import { Repository, EntityRepository } from 'typeorm';

import { Vehicle } from '../models/Vehicle';

@EntityRepository(Vehicle)
export class VehicleRepository extends Repository<Vehicle>  {

}
```

TypeORM version is

```
"typeorm": "^0.2.12",
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: What is your `query` here??Can you post the query??

Comment: whether the query is forming properly `{
                            "vin": vin.vin,
                            "userId": user.Id
                        }` by replacing the value??